# Object keep reference's track but doesn't keep it in the object

Tags: javascript, object, reference

When passing an object to function as a parameter and using it to create a separate object by Object.create you get an empty object.
But if you then use this new object to refer to a specific parameter that was set in initial object you'll get initial object's parameter value.

I would expect those values to be included in the new object or at least can't be reached within it.

```js
var o = { baz: [] };
o.rrr = { a: 1 };
console.log( o, '"o" before timeout called' );

setTimeout(function() { n(o) }, 1000); // setting delay

function n(x) {
  console.log( 'x - what we passed', x );
  var obj = Object.create( x );
  console.log( obj, '"obj" before enhancements is empty' );
  console.log( obj.rrr, 'but "obj.rrr" do exist' );
  obj.baz = [];

  obj.baz.push( 'new value' );
  console.log( obj, '"obj" after enhancements contain "baz" only' );
  console.log( obj.rrr, 'but "obj.rrr" still exist' );
  console.log( o, '"o" after timeout ended' );
  console.log( '---- THE END ----' );
}

console.log( o, '"o" after timeout called' );
```

How so?

Can you get rid of those references while keeping the structure?

Can you otherwise get those values set in your new object from the begining (like cloning it)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - that codepen you posted clearly shows that the "empty" object [is *not* empty](https://i.imgur.com/XbIp6uk.png)

Comment: [This what I see](https://imgur.com/a/8O0ec0c)

Comment: Did you try clicking the arrow and expanding the view?

Comment: Yes. It will include `baz: ["new value"]` and `__proto__: Object`. But if I remeber it correctly chrome console will resolve those values later on and they don't necessary represent aqual state of affairs at moment of output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) method creates a new object, using `x` as the prototype of the newly created object. So, the property `rrr` directly doesn't exist in `obj`. It exists in it's `[[Prototype]]` (or `__proto__`)

```js
var x = { prop: 1 }
var y = Object.create(x)

console.log(y.prop) // 1
console.log("prop" in y) // true
console.log(y.__proto__ === x) // true
console.log(y.hasOwnProperty("prop")) // false
```

The `in` operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object or **its prototype chain**. So, in this case, it returns true.

But, the [`hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method on the other hand, returns a boolean indicating whether the object has a property as **its own property**. This is why `y.hasOwnProperty("prop")` returns false even though `y.prop` returns 1.

If you want to get the properties directly in `y`, you can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) instead. This copies all the enumerable own properties from `x` to an empty target object.

```js
var x = { prop: 1 }
var y = Object.assign({}, x)

console.log(y.prop) // 1
console.log(y.hasOwnProperty("prop")) // true
```

Comment: If it's based in prototype why do i get it's value simply by y.prop then?

Comment: @WhatEver because that's what `[[Prototype]]` does in javascript. If `prop` doesn't exist in `y`, it checks it's prototope chain. `y.__proto__.prop`. For example, how can you call `toString()` on objects even if you don't add the method manually? If the objects don't have a `toString()` method, it falls back to `Object.prototype` and it uses `Object.prototype.toString()`

Comment: I thought [[Prototype]] copied structure but not values. How can I get this kind of behavior?

Comment: @WhatEver it doesn't copy anything. The parameter to `Object.create` is set as the new object's [[Prototype]] or `__proto__`. So, `var y = Object.create(x); y.__proto__ === x` <- This Strict Equality returns true. Also, `x.__proto__ === Object.prototype` This is why you'll be able to use `toString()` and other methods.

Comment: I see. So `Object.create(x)` creates an empty object with reference to `__proto__`. Thnx.

Comment: And as i get it you actualy can edit the value of `__proto__` like without `obj.baz = [];` this part `obj.baz.push( 'new value' );` will result in pushing this value to `o.baz`

Comment: @WhatEver yes. Because there is no `baz` property in `obj`. It pushes to `obj.__proto__.baz`